# How to replace a function call in an existing method

Tags: python, monkeypatching

given a module with a class Foo with a method that calls a function `bar` defined in the module scope, is there a way to substitute `bar` for a different function without modification to the module?

```
class Foo(object):
    def run(self):
        bar()

def bar():
    return True
```

I then have a an instance of `Foo` for which I would like to substitute a function `baz()` for `bar()` without having to modify the `Foo` class.

Comment: do you want to change for just the single instance without affecting any other instance?

Comment: My application would work either way.  I could modify the class or each instance as needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's assume your module is called `deadbeef`, and you're using it like this

```
import deadbeef
…
foo_instance = deadbeef.Foo()
```

Then you could do

```
import deadbeef
deadbeef.bar = baz 
…
```

Comment: Note that this - while not technically affecting the Foo class - does apply this changed behaviour to all instances of `Foo`.

Comment: Will this actually change `bar` that is called by `foo_instance.run()`? Or will that `bar` still be mapped to the original function def that has since been overwritten by `baz`? Is the method `foo.run` only created and thus bound to `bar` when the class is instantiated? This is one place where Python references always get me.

Comment: I just discovered that this does **not** work if the module is loaded using `%run deadbeef.py`.  In this case if I replace `bar = baz`, for some reason the class still has a copy of the original `bar`.  Can anyone explain why?

Comment: @Mike `%run` looks like it's an IPython directive? I really don't know what that does, but my guess is it sets up a clean namespace, and manually runs `deadbeef.py` in that, so that modifications you did to your *module* namespace don't have any effect. To me, this looks like it would be like that  by design – when `run`ning a file, I'd expect the file to be clean-slate evaluated, not imported atop of what's already imported

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist `deadbeef` is a hommage to one of the typical "debug" words that one uses, eg. to easily find endianness or bit flip problems. The cool thing is `0xDEADBEEF` is a fully valid 32 bit word :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Fantastic. I guess I'd seen it around and even kind of realized it could be hex, but I never knew its history. TMYK.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I used to use `0xB00B1E5`, but you don't notice a byte reversal in the upper 16bit with that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have always been under the impression that the IPython `%run` magic command run the script in the common namespace of the notebook. I often use it in place of `import` to quickly reload when I edit the module instead of the headache of reloading an imported module. In my experience it runs as if it was inline in the current IPython session.

Answer (score 4):

You can monkey patch `Foo` at run time, and override the method `run`.

For example if `foo` is instance of `Foo` you can do:

```
def run(obj): 
    baz()

foo.run = run
```

Next time you call `foo.run` it will invoke `baz`.

See more here http://blog.tryolabs.com/2013/07/05/run-time-method-patching-python/

Comment: because you are setting a instance variable instead of the class method it wouldn't take the object as the first argument, so just doing `foo.run = baz` would be sufficient. Also note that this will only change the one instance instead of all instances of `Foo` but doesn't work for magic methods. (may or may not be applicable to OP)

Comment: It is fairly straightforward to replace the method `foo.run`, however what I want to replace is function called within `foo.run` without having to re-implement the entire method. I believe that the `bar` function in my example is bound to `foo.run` when the class is declared so just replacing `bar=baz` will not change `foo.run`.

Answer (score 0):

I asked something similar recently and **staticmethod** was the answer (because your baz and bar dont seem to be methods).  Basically, you want to do something like the Strategy Pattern and call a different function from run().

```
def bar():
    print "I am bar()"
    return True

def baz():
    print "I am baz()"
    return True

class Foo(object):

    # default to running bar.
    torun = staticmethod(bar)

    def run(self):
        self.torun()

foo = Foo()

foo.run()

foo2 = Foo()
foo2.torun = baz

foo2.run()
```

output:

```
I am bar()
I am baz()
```

You could assign pretty much whatever you wanted to your foo instance, including functions defined on a different module.  And run could take *args and **kwds for more flexibility.